# Does ColdFusion Builder have split screen editing like Homesite+, and how do I turn it on?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

Does ColdFusion Builder have split screen editing like Homesite+, and how do I turn it on?  How do I activate word wrap?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to see 2 files tiled at the same time within ColdFusion Builder 2, follow the steps below:

1. Open the file
2. Right click the tab with the file name
3. Choose Move Editor
4. You will see the file outlined in black in the interface, it is now attached to your cursor
5. Click to the right of the Source tab in the open area
6. This will allow you to view both files at the same time, one above the other
7. The file you select will be the active file
8. You can still use the Source and browser tabs, they will reflect whatever file is the active one

Word Wrap:

Go to Window > Preferences > HTML > Editors. Click the Advanced tab and check Enable word wrap. Restart CF Builder.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare 2 files, there is an easier way.

1. Select both files
2. Right-click one of them
3. Select 'Compare With --> Each Other

Eclipse will then show you the 2 files side by side, and highlight any differences.

Answer (score 0):

ColdFusion Builder 2016 (AKA 3.1) offers "split view" for both horizontal (CTRL+_) & vertical (CTRL+{), but the hotkeys don't appear to work at the moment.  This can be accessed via the "Window | Editor" menu.  You can also search the "Quick Access" search box and type "Split" and then choose the toggle options that appear.

Answer (score 0):

In ColdFusion Builder 2016 the keyboard shortcut is: (CTRL+SHIFT+_) AND (CTRL+SHIFT+{)